# Shell Script :How to pass script's command-line arguments through to commands that it invokes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

So far "`ls`" works fine i take all files in the directory. But now i want when i execute `./myscript ls -l /somedir`  to take the same results as i take when i type `ls -l /somedir` at the terminal.

Is there any way to make it?
This is my code so far..

```
#!/bin/sh
clear

echo ""
read  -p "type something :  " file
    echo""
    IFS=:
    for dir in $PATH ; do  

        if [ -x "$dir/$file" ]
        then

        echo ""
          exec "$dir/$file" 

        fi
        done
```

Comment: You mean pipe the output of `ls -1 somedir` to yourscript.sh? e.g. `ls -1 /somedir | sh yourscript.sh` ?

Comment: I realise that the comments don't display properly, but can you try explaining, in words, what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: well my script can execute a program that is located at some directory of the $PATH by giving its name. Also by typing `ls` i take back the files of the directory. Now i want when i type `ls -l / tmp` to take as return what i would take by typing `ls -l /tmp` at `user@user:~$` at my terminal. @aho

Comment: This is a bit confusing; perhaps it's a language barrier, perhaps it's you not quite understanding. If you type "ls -l /tmp" or "ls -l / tmp" at your terminal, your script will not be invoked. In order to invoke your script, you'd have to run your script. What is the name of the file in which your script is written? And how would you like to invoke it?

Comment: There's no point to launch a command into the background, and then the next thing you do is wait for it to finish.

Comment: i just want to make my script able to run `ls -l / tmp` . now when i type it nothing comes to output. i want an output like the one the terminal gives. @aho

Comment: as glenn jackman says, there's no need to background your command (so get rid of the ampersand and the wait. Then, try running your command using: `eval "$dir/$file"`

Comment: I tried `eval` but nothing. Also i have to use `&`. Any ideas? @aho

Comment: How is this script supposed to run `ls -l`? I mean, reading it, it's plain on its face that that isn't what it does.

Comment: Also, "have to use `&`"? Huh? Why? Does it fail if you don't? How, and with what message? Is this a class lesson / exercise where that's mandatory? If so, you're probably misunderstanding the instructor's intent, since running something in the background and immediately waiting is the same as what the shell does if you just run it in the foreground.

Comment: Yes,I know that is the same. But i have to make the execution on a child process as the exercise asks. That's why i use `&`. Isn't right? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: No; `ls` **always** runs in a child process, since it isn't built into bash. An example of putting directory contents into a native shell array which didn't use a child process would be `files=( * )` (which is, incidentally, the correct / best-practices way to do it).

Comment: I also use the script to execute,in a child process, other scripts stored at the $PATH.Not only for `ls`. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Sure, but if it's an "other script", executed rather than sourced in, it's run in a separate shell instance -- and thus in a child process. And since you only run things by executing their filename, and not with `source` or `.`, you're **always** executing things as separate processes.

Comment: BTW -- this whole question would be much, much clearer if instead of asking "how to ls -l some dir" you asked "how do I pass my script's command-line arguments through to commands that it invokes?" -- assuming that that's actually what you're trying to do.

Comment: ...similarly, there's a bunch of cruft in here that has nothing to do with your question (like all the `check` and `checkout` mess). As documented at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, you should be removing things not absolutely necessary to reproduce a bug **before** you ask a question.

Comment: Or do you mean you want to type `ls -l file` at the `read` prompt? Of **course** that won't work, because `[ -x "/usr/bin/ls -l file" ]` will never be true (unless someone actually made a program by that name, of course).

Comment: ...and the naive solutions will leave you with bugs where you can't handle command-line argument lists with quotes, escaping, etc. Why are you bothering to iterate through PATH yourself rather than letting the shell doing it anyhow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it (which involves a great deal of guesswork, as the question is not clearly asked), your problem is that command-line arguments aren't passed through.

Use `"$@"` to access them:

```
#!/bin/bash
prog=$1; shift
IFS=: read -r -a paths <<<"$PATH"
for path in "${paths[@]}"; do
  [[ -x $path/$prog ]] && "$path/$prog" "$@"
done
```

Then, running `yourscript ls -l /foo` will actually pass the `-l` and the `/foo` through to any instance of `ls` they create.